# Linux: How to finish/interrupt the `less` command in "&<pattern>" mode

Tags: linux, pattern-matching, text-processing, less-unix

Using `Linux` I want to know how to go back to normal file view with `less` whenever I used the  `& <pattern>` format in the `less` to search for **only** the lines with the `pattern` I am looking for.

I know that I can type`q` or `^z` BUT these terminate the `less`. However, I **DO not want to quit the `less`** and I just want to do see the only lines with `pattern` and **then go back to previous `less` environment**.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `&` again with no pattern, i.e. enter `&` and hit return.